# Extracting value dynamically from dictionary on helm2

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to run a bit of a complicated helm chart, and need some help.

I'm trying to get value from a dictionary like that:

```
get .myDictionary .Values.dictionaryKey
```

Unfortunately, looks like get function is not supported in helm 2 which I'm using.
Do you have any advice on how to get the dictionary value with dynamic value coming from a variable on helm2?

Comment: helm2 includes the [sprig dict helpers](https://masterminds.github.io/sprig/dicts.html) which should have `get`. What's the issue when using it?

Comment: When trying to use it with helm2 I'm getting 
`function "get" not defined`

Comment: what versions of helm2/tiller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The core Go [`text/template`](https://godoc.org/text/template) language contains a `index` function that does what you're looking for.

```
{{ index .myDictionary .Values.dictionaryKey }}
```

Answer (score 4):

Apparently helm v2 uses sprig version 1 which doesn't have the get function (which was added only on v3).

The found solution in helm v2 is to use `pluck "keyName" $dict | first`.

Comment: [fairly recent in sprig](https://github.com/Masterminds/sprig/commit/d4e8594bf4251d8417d4740709aaa82a726266a5)